# How Often Do You Power Down Your Linux System?

Tags: linux

How often do you actually shut down your Linux desktops/laptops (servers excluded for the obvious reason)? Do you power down when you’re not using it, every evening when you are done, or never – unless a power outage happens? What do you recommend? I used to never shut down but I find myself doing it more and more, at least every couple of days. I'm also not talking about rebooting; I'm talking about powering down and keeping it powered down for a little bit.

Comment: This is a 100% opinion-based question, and is probably off-topic at all Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: You can rent a small linux VPS for us$5/mo, or sometimes free (Amazon EC2 Free Tier).  Electricity being around $0.10/kwh, a tower-style computer and monitor using 100W for 24hrs/day will use 72kWh/month  electricity for an energy cost of $7.20/month.

Answer (score 1):

Although an opinion based question, I can chip in some of my own opinions here as well.

Lets look at the three power-down options available in your average computer nowaadys

**Sleep**

Sleep is actually a low-power state. The computer must be using some amount of energy to power up your RAM ( to keep your content intact ) and to respond to a wake-up a signal but the over-all power consumption in sleep-mode is minimal.

*When to use?* Put the computer to sleep when you are are just getting up from your work for a small period of time, maybe like an hour or two or to get a cup of coffee with some colleagues in the cafeteria, or to answer the telephone or some event that takes a relatively small time.

**Hibernate**

Similar to sleep mode but the difference is that unlike sleep-mode where content is saved in RAM, hibernate will put the contents of RAM inside hard-disk and then power off your computer. So technically it is least of the power consuming mode. *When to use* when you are to leave your computer for extended period of time ranging from 3 to 8 hours and you want your content to load up at the same point as you had left

**Shutdown**

We all know what this option is for. When you are not expecting to use the computer for a longer period of time and you dont want your open documents to load up again the next time, you can safely power off the machine.

Now all these time ranges and reasons are opinion based and my requirements may differ from yours. So there isn't any definite answer to your question